# Symfony 3.4 how can I create a login page via mobile number

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a project with Symfony 3.4
I want to have a login page and I want to login via mobile number.
but I have some errors such as "Invalid Credentials" on login.

my security class is like this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        API\V1\UsersBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt


    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        db_provider:
             entity: { class: API\V1\UsersBundle\Entity\User, property: mobile }


    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        panel:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                  login_path : panel_login
                  check_path : panel_login
                  username_parameter: _mobile
                  password_parameter: _password

            logout:
                  path : /panel_logout
                  target : /panel_login

    access_control:
        # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
        - { path: ^/login , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
        - { path: ^/panel/login , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
        - { path: ^/panel , roles : IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

and Entity class : User.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: nano byte
 * Date: 2/11/2019
 * Time: 3:14 AM
 */

namespace API\V1\UsersBundle\Entity;
use API\V1\UsersBundle\Enum\UserRoles;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("mobile")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $register_at;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",nullable = true)
     */
    protected $last_visited;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
     */
    protected $sui;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
     */
    protected $first_name;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable = true,length=255)
     */
    protected $last_name;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable = true,length=255)
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(unique=true,type="string",length=30)
     */
    protected $mobile;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
     */
    protected $relation;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50)
     */
    protected $location;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
     */
    protected $password;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable = true,length=255)
     */
    protected $pic;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",length=1, options={ "default":1})
     */
    protected $is_active;




    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set registerAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $registerAt
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRegisterAt($registerAt)
    {
        $this->register_at = $registerAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get registerAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getRegisterAt()
    {
        return $this->register_at;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastVisited
     *
     * @param \DateTime $lastVisited
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastVisited($lastVisited)
    {
        $this->last_visited = $lastVisited;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastVisited
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getLastVisited()
    {
        return $this->last_visited;
    }

    /**
     * Set sui
     *
     * @param string $sui
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSui($sui)
    {
        $this->sui = $sui;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sui
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSui()
    {
        return $this->sui;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->first_name = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->last_name = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set mobile
     *
     * @param string $mobile
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setMobile($mobile)
    {
        $this->mobile = $mobile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get mobile
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMobile()
    {
        return $this->mobile;
    }

    /**
     * Set relation
     *
     * @param string $relation
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRelation($relation)
    {
        $this->relation = $relation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get relation
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRelation()
    {
        return $this->relation;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param string $location
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set pic
     *
     * @param string $pic
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPic($pic)
    {
        $this->pic = $pic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pic
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPic()
    {
        return $this->pic;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param integer $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->is_active = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->is_active;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     *     public function getRoles()
     *     {
     *         return ['ROLE_USER'];
     *     }
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return (Role|string)[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getRoles() method.
        return UserRoles::getPossibleValues();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    /**
     * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * @return string The username
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getUsername() method.
        return $this->mobile;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
}
```

and my Controller for login and logout is like this :

```
/**
     * @Route("/panel/login" , name="panel_login")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request,AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils){


        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUserName = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('login.html.twig',array("error"=>$error,"username"=>$lastUserName));

    }

/**
 * @Route("/panel/logout" , name="panel_logout")
 */
public function logoutAction(){


}
```

and twig file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/admin/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css') }}">
    <!-- Bootstrap rtl -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/admin/dist/css/rtl.css') }}">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/bower_components/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/admin/dist/css/AdminLTE.css') }}">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css') }}">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
    <div class="login-logo">
        <a href="../../index2.html"><b>Visit Site</b></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-logo -->
    <div class="login-box-body">

        {% if error %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <div>{{ error.messageKey }}</div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

        <form name="login_form" action="{{ url('panel_login') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="_mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" value="{{ username }}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="_password ">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">  Remember Me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign in</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
            <p>- یا -</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Sign in using facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>Sign in using Google+</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

        <a href="#">I forgot my password</a><br>
        <a href="register.html" class="text-center">Register a new membership</a>

    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

<script src="{{ asset('public/bower_components/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- iCheck -->
<script src="{{ asset('public/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('input').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
            increaseArea: '20%' // optional
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Would you please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
it was just a mistake.
I put password filed as name="_password " in my form login.
I must remove extra space from it.